# why clojure conj acts different between vector and map

Tags: vector, clojure

```
> (conj [0] 1 2 3)
[0 1 2 3]
> (conj {:a "ei"} {:b "bi"})
{:b "bi", :a "ei"}
>
```

See, when it acts on vector, it puts 1,2,3 at end of it.
Whereas it put :b "bi" in front of :a map k-v pair
Why is this?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many hashed maps implementations, [Clojure's hashed maps](http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Maps) do not sort their entries, not retain the order in which they were inserted. This allows for better performance.

Note that [conj](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/conj) does not have general ordering semantics either (it has ordering semantics for some concrete types, such as vectors).

Comment: Conj has semantics per concrete type. In other words, it is a polymorphic function.

Comment: [sorted-map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-map) is a clojure map that does sort its entries by key.

Comment: Also note that this polymorphism does not come from nowhere : this is not the purpose of a hash-map to be ordered. Its purpose is to be accessed from a value that have another meaning, i;e. to perform "joining" operations. The order so does not matter. else, There are vectors or sorted-maps

Comment: @Mars that's why I specifically wrote 'hashed maps', not maps (just re-using the terminology on clojure.org).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go as far as maps to get inconsistent behaviour from `conj`:

```
(conj [1] 2) ; [1 2]    
(conj (list 1) 2) ; (2 1)
```

Hash maps have *no defined order*. But, for any map,

- the `seq` of entries will always be the same
- the `vals` and `keys` will be in consistent order.

Thus, for map `m`,

```
(= (keys m) (map key m))
(= (vals m) (map val m))
(= m (zipmap (keys m) (vals m)))
```

Currently, this sequence seems to be independent of insertion order. I tested this on sets by randomly shuffling random integers.